# Trying to get customization of Sublime Text 3 Build system to work

Tags: sublimetext3

Does anyone know how automatic build systems work in 3083 right now? Because I am struggling to get it to do the right thing. (p.s. I am not an expert st3 customizer so I am probably just doing it wrong.)

My TypeScript.sublime-build file lives in ../Packages/User and contains:

```
{
"cmd": ["/usr/local/bin/tsc"],
"file_regex": "^(.+?) \\((\\d+),(\\d+)\\): (.+)$",
"selector": "source.TypeScript"
}
```

1. When I edit a .ts file the syntax highlighting is for TypeScript and that is also what is displayed in the bottom right corner. So from that I deduce that ST3 is correctly identifying the desired syntax for the file (although I am not sure where that happens.)
2. When I choose the TypeScript build system by hand and click CMD-B it runs the build and displays the output in the console, as I expected.
3. When I have "automatic" build system and I open a .ts file or change to a .ts file that was already open, ST3 again correctly identifies the syntax (bottom right in the window.) However when I click CMD-B it runs the last build method that I happened to have used.

I thought that the idea with automatic is that it would choose the build system based on the syntax identified via the file extension.

Does anyone understand this problem or correct my assumptions?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question. As far as I know automatic means that the build-system is automatically selected by sublime.  Automatic doesn't means that the project is build every time you modify a file. I think that you already know that and what you want is a build system based on files not on project.  Is that right? In addition, you say it works on 2083, did you mean 3083?

Comment: Thanks! I've added more details to my question maybe it will clarify.

Comment: You can use menu _Tools>Build With_ to see a list of the build systems you can select for the current file based on _selector_ field. This way you can change the build-system that will be used next times for that files.

Comment: Was that what you want or I'm still not getting it?

Answer (score 1):

Never figured out the problem. But I fully uninstalled ST3 and reinstalled it, with the package control and typescript packages and nothing more, and now it seems to work. Oh well. I guess not all the bugs are out yet.